# Find the area of the part of the surface $z=\ln (x^2+y^2+2)$ that lies above the disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Find the area of the part of the surface $z=\ln (x^2+y^2+2)$ that lies above the disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1$  by expressing the area in terms of a **single integral**

Let us suppose that the lateral surface area = $S$ between radius $0$ and $1.$

Equation of the surface, $z = \ln(x^2+y^2+2) = \ln (r^2+2)$

$
\begin{align}
S &= \int_0^12\pi r~ dl \ ,\text { where $dl$ is the arc length} \\
& = \int_0^12\pi r \sqrt{1+(\frac{dz}{dr})^2}.dr \\
& = \int_0^12\pi r \sqrt{1+\dfrac {4r^2}{(r^2+2)^2}}.dr \\
& = \int_0^1\dfrac{2\pi r}{r^2+2} \sqrt{(r^2+4)^2-(2 \sqrt 3)^2}.dr
\end{align}
$

Put, $u = r^2+2 \implies du=2r~dr$ . Then:

\begin{align}
S & = \int_2^3 \dfrac{\pi}{u}\sqrt{(u+2)^2-(2 \sqrt3)^2} .du \\\end{align}

Mathematica describes quite a complicated way of solving this integration. Could someone tell me an easier way of solving this. Thank you!

Comment: The problem says "express the area as a single integral". The problem does **not** say "evaluate the integral" or "express the area as a numerical quantity." I don't think that you are supposed to do anything to "solve" the integration here.

Comment: $\displaystyle u +3 = 2\,\sqrt{\, 3\,}\, \cosh\left(\theta\right)$.